# "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" when deleting in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm stumped...

I get "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" when the view attempts to delete an instance."

The exception is thrown on the line "form.instance.delete()"

Here's the code:

**view.py**

```
def decorate_letter(request, ...):    
....
if request.POST:
    flair_formset = flair_formset_factory(request.POST or None)
    for form in flair_formset.forms:
        if form.has_changed():
            if form.is_valid():
                if form.cleaned_data['delete'] == 1:
                    form.instance.delete()
                elif form not in flair_formset.deleted_forms:
                    form.save()
```

**models.py**

```
class LetterFlair(models.Model):
    letter = models.ForeignKey(Letter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    flair = models.ForeignKey(Flair, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    x = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, default=0)
    y = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, default=0)
    r = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, default=0)
    placed = models.CharField(default='false', max_length=250)
    delete = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**forms.py**

```
class LetterFlairModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = LetterFlair
        fields = ['letter', 'flair', 'x', 'y', 'r', 'placed', 'delete']
```

**stack trace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File ".../python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../letters/views.py", line 140, in decorate_letter
    form.instance.delete()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

What could be causing the exception?

**Update**

I've added a stack trace to my question.

I'm genuinely not sure which part of my codes is leading to this question and hence have posted more than I usually would.

**Update 2**

Now that it's clear where the error originated from, for what it's worth I've slimmed down the posted code.

Comment: The exception message should tell you exactly where in the source code the exception occurs. The stack trace should tell you exactly where in the execution the exception occurs. Also, please make sure to provide a [mre]. I don't think it requires 50 lines of code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for your feedback. I'm unclear on what of my code is leading to this exception, so it seemed prudent to post more than I usually would. I've added a stack trace to my answer, but I'm not sure how it helps me understand what's wrong.

Comment: The error tells you that `form.instance.delete` is an integer, but it should be a method. Your task is to isolate where that happens in the code. If I were you, I'd use an IDE and search for all references to the `delete` member of whatever class `instance` is. Once you have that, you can use a debugger or prints to see where `delete` is overwritten with an int.

Comment: Thanks @AgostBiro! I can do that :)

Comment: @AgostBiro - never name one of your model fields delete! Changing to deleted and migrating the model solved the problem. Really appreciate your suggestion. I will edit my question inline with what I now know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AgostBiro pointed me in the right direction and I've pinpointed the cause of the problem in that I named one of the fields 'delete' which overwrote the delete() method. Renaming to deleted and migrating the model fixed the problem.